# How to specify the token url for a custom external named credential

Tags: oauth2, namedcredentials

I need to make a Oauth 2.0 callout to an external system. Unfortunately it doesn't seem that I can use Auth. Providers as the external system also requires a username and password and there's no way to populate these in Auth. Providers.

Reading [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custom_headers_and_api_keys.htm&type=5) it seems that I can set up the username and password in the header using External Named Credentials. However I am unsure of how to specify the auth url and token url after that.

Also inside Named Credentials I see that a formula could be used inside HTTP Body. I couldn't find where I am supposed to populate that. Is there even documentation for this, couldn't find anything.
[image]

**UPDATE**
The service I am trying to is using a Client Credentials Flow.
[image]

Comment: The answer to your question depends on how the service you're target wants to receive these items. Please edit your question and provide this detail.

Comment: @identigral - What do you mean by how the service wants to receive these items? It's a Oauth 2.0. Can you give me an example of what else you would like me to add to my question? Thank you.

Comment: Which oAuth flows does your target service support and which flow are you trying to implement?

Comment: @identigral - My bad, I updated my question. Thanks again.

Comment: @identigral I believe so, thank you. That's what I was thinking.